# Bash: Copy A Folder Into Itself Indefinitely

Tags: bash, copy, directory, infinite

Say I have folder copyMe, and I want it to copy *into itself* forever. Just nesting further and further. How would I do that?

Comment: On what system?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a silly thing to do, but if I wanted to do that, I'd use symbolic links:

```
mkdir ~/a
ln -s ~/a ~/a/a
cd ~/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

On `Linux` and `Unix` do:

```
while :
do
    mkdir copyMe/
    cd copyMe/
done
```

Comment: Yes, it's Unix. Thanks.